# Determine the smallest value of $k$ corresponding to the level of significance $α = 0.01$

Tags: statistics

> You have a coin and $p$ is the probability of heads.  
>   You throw the coin until you obtain heads for the first time. 
>   You want to test $H_0:p=1/2$ against $H_1:p<1/2$. You reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_1$ if $T ≥ k$, where $T$ is the number of the throw which yielded heads for the first time and $k$ an integer. 
>   Determine the smallest value of $k$ corresponding to the level of significance $α = 0.01$.

Answer $k=8$

I can't find the correct solution for this question, how it's possible to have $H_1:p<1/2$ and then they say that we reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_1$ if $T ≥ k$, shouldn't they be in the same direction? 
I have to compute $P(T>k|H_0)=P(T>k|p=1/2)$ right? How can I compute it?

Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: look up the geometric distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction. You need to solve the inequality $P(T\geq k|p=\frac{1}{2})\leq 0.01$.
(I hope this makes sense for you, as this is just the definition of [level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)) of the test. Some authors also call it **size**. But there is a distinction between them. For e.g. look [here](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~pritamr/stat450_04/levelalpha.pdf). To be more precise, if you are given the size for the  test of a simple hypothesis, we would have used equality sign above. )

$T$ being the total no. of throws required for obtaining the first head, its probability distribution can be computed as mentioned in the comment above. I would apply rather an intuitive method to do the same.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(T\geq k|p=\frac{1}{2})&=1-P(T<k)=1-\left[P(T=1)+P(T=2)+\dots_+P(T=k-1)\right]  \\
&=1-\left[\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\dots+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\right]\\&\mbox{(When we say that $T=i, i>1$, we mean that the first $(i-1)$ results in tails.  }\\
&\hspace{2mm} \mbox{Head is obtained only on the $i^{th}$ toss. Since the trials are independent, this  }\\
&\hspace{2mm}\mbox{probability is just $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-1}.\frac{1}{2}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i}$})\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\leq 0.01
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The least value of $k$ for which this holds is $8$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, now the method that you use is clear, the only thing is that I don't understand how to arrive to $(1-\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}$ from the previous equation.

Comment: I am happy that I am able to provide you a little helping hand in order to understand the concept

Comment: Thank you a lot, but what principle do you use to arrive at $(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}$?

Comment: Hint:-If you are familiar with G.P. it is easy to calculate $\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\dots+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}$. This is the sum of first $k$ terms of a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$. For a G.P with first term $a$ and common ratio $r(<1)$, the sum of first $k$ terms is given y $\frac{a(1-r^k)}{1-r}$.

Comment: I hope now it is clear to you how I obtained $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}$. On applying the above formula you would get the required result

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now with this formula is clear how to obtain it! :)